# "errors encountered while discovering extensions" in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using a UIImagePickerController to send a user-selected image to an API, but am getting this error:

`warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.
 [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}`

This is the code in which the error occurs:

```
NSError *error;
NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
    [body appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
    if (param[@"fileName"]) {
        [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", param[@"name"], param[@"fileName"]];
        [body appendFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", param[@"contentType"]];
        [body appendFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:param[@"fileName"] encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding/*NSUTF8StringEncoding*/ error:&error]];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    } else {
        [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param[@"name"]];
        [body appendFormat:@"%@", param[@"value"]];
    }
}
[body appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];
NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

That code is inside this method: `(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info`.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me was simply going into Product (at the top of the screen) -> Scheme -> EditScheme -> Arguments

In Environment Variables, add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE with a value of "disable"

Hopefully this works for someone else!

I'll attach a screenshot just in case my description seemed confusing[image]

Comment: Setting OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to disable, disables the log statements, it does not actually fix anything. By doing this you also are hiding other potentially important logs in the console.